# Cannot resolve dependencies (Maven and Gradle) with Google Artifacts Registry

Tags: google-artifact-registry

I'm facing problem with artifact registry

I use Gradle, I can publish a jar
But I cannot download dependency

I try also with Maven, same thing, I can publish but not download

There are very few informations on internet and no support

- I run

> gcloud auth application-default login

- I'm connected to GCP
- I copy paste the code from the interface : https://console.cloud.google.com/artifacts/maven/mmnb-299822/us-east1/maven?hl=fr&project=abc-123

```
plugins {
  id "maven-publish"
  id "com.google.cloud.artifactregistry.gradle-plugin" version "2.1.1"
}

publishing {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url "artifactregistry://us-east1-maven.pkg.dev/abc-a123/maven"
    }
  }
}

repositories {
  maven {
    url "artifactregistry://us-east1-maven.pkg.dev/abc-a123/maven"
  }
}
```

Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

Here is a template on how you can download dependencies on Maven.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>group</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
<dependencies>
```

And here is the template for Gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'group', name: 'artifact', version: '1.0'
}
```

You must also consider that this is in Alpha stage and can have limited support. To get more information about this topic, please visit the official documentation page for [Managing Packages for AR](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/java/manage-packages#maven_1).

Comment: yes I have a dependency to my package. That not works

Comment: Does it show any error when it's failing Any additional information you can provide?

Comment: Same problem here. I have followed the steps as @Maryo comments, and when I try to recover the dependency with Maven, it tells me that it could not find it. I put in Maven pom an exact copy of what Google Artifact Registry tells me

`Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not resolve dependencies for project blorks.corp:ms-misiones:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact blorks.corp:base-repo:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT`